# inserting 8k + character strings into azure sql data warehouse using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, azure, pyodbc, azure-synapse

As the title states, im trying to insert an 8k+ string into azure sql data warehouse using pyodbc in a python notebook. I've seen a few answers related to changing the driver, and ive updated to latest driver which supposedly supports this, still no luck.

Heres the code i'm using

```
import pyodbc
connectionString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=myServerInfo;Database=myDB;Uid=user;Pwd={pw};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;LongAsMax=1;"
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)

cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

sql = "insert into myTable (id, veryLongText) values (?, ?)" 
params = (1, 'a' * 8001) 

cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

this gives the error

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]104220;Cannot find data type 'text'. (100000) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

if i truncate the string to 4k characters, i dont have any issues, but unfort i need all the data as is for the project.

I've tried casting the long string to varchar(max) to see if i can force the driver to use varchar(max) instead of text

```
sql = "insert into myTable (id, veryLongText) values (?, cast(? as varchar(max))"
```

which gives the error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Insert values statement can contain only constant literal values or variable references. (104334) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I've also tried using `pyodbc.Binary` to cast the string into a varchar(max) datatype (chatgpts reommendation lol) but i get this error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Unsupported data type error. Statement references a data type that is unsupported in Parallel Data Warehouse, or there is an expression that yields an unsupported data type. Modify the statement and re-execute it. (104051) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

can anyone shed some light on how I can fix this?

Updates:

using SiddheshDesai's answer, I've tried inserting using a stored procedure instead, but I'm getting the same error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertLongText
    @id int,
    @veryLongText varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myTable (id, veryLongText) VALUES (@id, @veryLongText)
END
```

```
sql = "EXEC InsertLongText ?, ?"

params = (1, 'a' * 8001)

  

cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]104220;Cannot find data type 'text'. (100000) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

It seems the issue is with the driver and SQL Pools (formally known as SQL data warehouse). Specifically, I am using Azure Synapse Analytics

Answer (score 0):

***I created a myTable in Azure SQL  and Inserted the string successfully, Refer below:-***

Created **myTable** with stored procedure in the SQL DB :-

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id int,
    veryLongText varchar(max)
)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertLongText
    @id int,
    @veryLongText varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myTable (id, veryLongText) VALUES (@id, @veryLongText)
END

Select * from myTable
GO
```

***Installed Pyodbc MS SQL Driver 17 from the link below:-***

[Download ODBC Driver for SQL Server - ODBC Driver for SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#version-17)

Used the below Python code to Insert the string :-

```py
import  pyodbc

  

connectionString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=azure-sql-server.database.windows.net;Database=azuresqldb;Uid=siliconuser;Pwd=<password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;LongAsMax=1;"

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)

  

cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')

cnxn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')

  

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

  

sql = "EXEC InsertLongText ?, ?"

params = (1, 'a' * 8001)

  

cursor.execute(sql, params)

cursor.execute('Select * From myTable' )

for  i  in  cursor:

print(i)

cnxn.commit()

cursor.close()

cnxn.close()
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: Hmm I updated to use the stored procedure, but I'm still getting the error
```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]104220;Cannot find data type 'text'. (100000) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```
Your answer says you created a table in Azure SQL, but I am using Azure SQL pool ( formerly known as azure SQL data warehouse), so I'm unsure if that's where the discrepancy lies.

Comment: Did you try installing ODBC Driver 17 in your SQL pool instead of ODBC Driver 18? Download https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#version-17 and then try connecting to your SQL pool?

Comment: Indeed, i originally updated from 17 to 18 in the hopes it would fix this issue.